# Form submits on button click even with type of button

Tags: ajax, forms, vue.js

I'm trying to submit a form with ajax using vuejs it works pretty well however when I click enter on the field input field the form submits as if it is submitting to itself. I'm using form role=form and button type=button and the button is even outside of the form itself but yet im having this problem. It also places values in the get string like so codernoob.com?userName=testUser1 
The form isn't that complex the only thing im doing that's a little bit crazy is hiding and showing two forms depending on what they click.

*NOTE: It only does this on the Reset Password Form*

```
<?php session_start(); 
ob_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['activated'])) {
    $activated = $_SESSION['activated'];
  }
?>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
       <!--vuejs-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
          <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="custom.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="logInApp" v-cloak>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
         <div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
             <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             </button>

             <?php if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) != 'templates.php') {
                echo '  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 171 171" style="enable-background:new 0 0 171 171;" xml:space="preserve">
                    <path class="st0" d="M153.4,91l-30.2,8c-4.2,11.5-13.5,20.6-26.1,24.1c-20.7,5.7-42.2-6.5-48-27.2c-5.7-20.7,6.5-42.2,27.2-48
                        c15.9-4.4,32.5,0.9,41.9,15.1l-19.5,5.3c-3.4-2.4-7.6-3.8-12-3.8c-11.6,0-20.9,9.4-20.9,20.9s9.4,20.9,20.9,20.9
                        c8.5,0,15.8-5.1,19.1-12.3L153.5,81l0.7,0l11.4-6.7L163,62.6l-13.1-1.3l-4.3-9.1l7.3-11l-7.4-9.4l-12.4,4.5l-7.9-6.4l1.8-13.1
                        l-10.7-5.2l-9.2,9.5l-9.8-2.3l-4-12.6L81.3,6.1l-4.2,12.5l-9.9,2.2l-9.1-9.6l-10.8,5.1L49,29.4l-7.9,6.2L28.7,31l-5.2,6.4l-2.3,2.9
                        v0l7.2,11.1l-0.9,1.8l-3.6,7.3l-13.2,1.1L8,73.1L19.3,80l-0.1,10.1L7.9,96.9l2.6,11.6l13.1,1.3l4.3,9.1l-7.3,11v0l3.7,4.7l3.7,4.7
                        l12.4-4.5l0.2,0.1l0,0l5.8,4.7l1.9,1.5l-1.8,13.1l10.7,5.2l9.2-9.5l9.8,2.3l4,12.6l11.9,0.1l4.2-12.5l9.9-2.2l9.1,9.6l10.8-5.1
                        l-1.6-13.1l7.9-6.2l12.4,4.7l7.5-9.3l-7.2-11.1l4.4-9.1l13.2-1.1l2.7-11.6L154.1,91L153.4,91z"/>
                    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 145.3561 17.4842)">TM</text>
                </svg><span class="logo-text">CreativeEngine</span></a>';
                } else {echo '<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 171 171" style="enable-background:new 0 0 171 171;" xml:space="preserve">
                    <path class="st0" d="M153.4,91l-30.2,8c-4.2,11.5-13.5,20.6-26.1,24.1c-20.7,5.7-42.2-6.5-48-27.2c-5.7-20.7,6.5-42.2,27.2-48
                        c15.9-4.4,32.5,0.9,41.9,15.1l-19.5,5.3c-3.4-2.4-7.6-3.8-12-3.8c-11.6,0-20.9,9.4-20.9,20.9s9.4,20.9,20.9,20.9
                        c8.5,0,15.8-5.1,19.1-12.3L153.5,81l0.7,0l11.4-6.7L163,62.6l-13.1-1.3l-4.3-9.1l7.3-11l-7.4-9.4l-12.4,4.5l-7.9-6.4l1.8-13.1
                        l-10.7-5.2l-9.2,9.5l-9.8-2.3l-4-12.6L81.3,6.1l-4.2,12.5l-9.9,2.2l-9.1-9.6l-10.8,5.1L49,29.4l-7.9,6.2L28.7,31l-5.2,6.4l-2.3,2.9
                        v0l7.2,11.1l-0.9,1.8l-3.6,7.3l-13.2,1.1L8,73.1L19.3,80l-0.1,10.1L7.9,96.9l2.6,11.6l13.1,1.3l4.3,9.1l-7.3,11v0l3.7,4.7l3.7,4.7
                        l12.4-4.5l0.2,0.1l0,0l5.8,4.7l1.9,1.5l-1.8,13.1l10.7,5.2l9.2-9.5l9.8,2.3l4,12.6l11.9,0.1l4.2-12.5l9.9-2.2l9.1,9.6l10.8-5.1
                        l-1.6-13.1l7.9-6.2l12.4,4.7l7.5-9.3l-7.2-11.1l4.4-9.1l13.2-1.1l2.7-11.6L154.1,91L153.4,91z"/>
                    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 145.3561 17.4842)">TM</text>
                </svg><span class="logo-text">CreativeEngine</span></a><ul class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm visible-xs"><li class="fa fa-search" data-target="#searchTemplatesModal" data-toggle="modal" id="templateSearchIcon"></li><ul>';}
                ?>
            </div><!--end .navbar-header-->
            <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li v-show="admin==true"><a href="adminMenu.php">Admin</a></li>
                <?php if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'templates.php'){echo '<li class="hidden-lg visible-md visible-sm hidden-xs"
                data-target="#searchTemplatesModal" data-toggle="modal"><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-search"></span> Search</a></li>
                <li class="visible-lg hidden-md hidden-sm visible-xs"><a href="templates.php">Templates</a></li>';}
                else{ echo '<li><a href="templates.php">Templates</a></li>';};?>
                <li><a href="#">Stock</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subscriptions</a></li>
                <li v-show="sessionLoggedIn==true"><a href="profile.php">Profile</a></li>
                <li v-show="sessionLoggedIn==false"><a v-on:click="showLoginForm();" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Login</a></li>
                <li v-show="sessionLoggedIn==true"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                <li><a href="signup.php">Signup</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div><!--end #navbar-->
         </div><!--end container-->
        </nav>
     <div class="container">
      <div id="loginModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!--Login -->
            <div v-show="showLoginContent==true" class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                <button v-on:click="resetLoginFormFields()" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
                <h2 class="modal-title">Login</h2><!--end modal-title-->
                </div>
                <!--end modal-header-->
                <div class="modal-body">
                <form role="form">
                    <!--Username-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username">Username/Email</label>
                        <input v-on:click="error=false; loginSub=false;" v-model="userName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username/Email" id="username" name="userName" v-on:keyup.enter="submit">
                        <a href="#">Forgot Username</a>
                    </div><!--end username-->
                    <!--Password-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input v-on:click="error=false; loginSub=false;" v-model="password" type="password"  v-on:keyup.enter="submit" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password">
                        <a href="#" v-on:click="showResetPasswordForm();">Forgot Password</a>
                    </div><!--end password-->

                    </form>
                 <div v-show="error==true || userName.length<=7 && loginSub==true || password.length<=7 && loginSub==true"><small class="error">Username/Email or password was incorrect...Try again</small>
                    </div><!--end incorrect password message-->
                </div><!--end modal-body-->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" v-on:click="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>
                </div><!--end modal-footer-->
            </div><!--end modal-content-->
            <!--end Login-->

            <!--Reset Password -->
            <div v-show="showResetPasswordContent==true" class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button v-on:click="resetLoginFormFields()" type="button" class="close">Back</button>
                <h2>Reset Password</h2>
                </div><!--end modal-header-->
                <div class="modal-body">
                <form role="form">
                    <!--Username/Email-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Username/Email</label>
                        <input v-on:focus="error=false; loginSub=false;" name="userName" v-model="userName" class="form-control" v-on:keyup.enter="resetPassword" v-on:keyup.delete="error=false; loginSub=false;">
                        <ul v-show="error==true || userFound==false">
                        <li v-show="error==true" class="error">Error reseting password. Please try again. If error prosists please contact the Creative Group.</li>
                        <li v-show="userFound==false" class="error">That username or email could not be found</li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul v-show="passwordResetSuccess==true">
                        <li class="success">Your password was successfully reset. Please check your email to obtain your new password.</li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul v-show="userName=='' && loginSub==true">
                            <li class="error">Please enter a username or email</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!--UserName/Email-->
                    </form>
                </div><!--end modal-body-->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" v-on:click="resetPassword" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Reset Password</button>
                </div><!--end modal-footer-->
            </div><!--end modal-content-->
            <!--end Reset Password-->
            </div><!--End modal-dialog-->
        </div><!-- End #loginModal -->


          <div class="modal fade" id="notActivatedModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <a href="logout.php" role="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</a>
          <h2 class="modal-title">Please Activate your account</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Please check your email and click on the activation link before signing in.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a href="logout.php" role="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Ok</a>     
          </div><!--end .modal-footer-->
        </div><!--end .modal-header-->
        </div><!--end modal-dialog-->
         </div><!-- end #notActivatedModal-->
        </div><!-- End .container-->
    </div><!-- End #loginApp-->

    <?php //Make the activation modal work so that they cant click off of it and forces them to activate their account.   
    if (isset($activated) && $activated == 0) {
      echo "<script>
      $('#notActivatedModal').modal('show');
      $('#notActivatedModal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});</script>";
  }
?>
        <script>
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#logInApp',
    data: {
      userName: '',
      password: '',
      error: '',
      loginSub: '',
      showLoginContent: true,
      showResetPasswordContent: false,
      userFound:true,
      passwordResetSuccess:false,
      response: [],
      sessionUserName: '<?php if (isset($_SESSION['userName'])) {echo $_SESSION['userName'];}?>',
      sessionEmail: '<?php if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) { echo $_SESSION['email'];}?>',
      sessionLoggedIn: '<?php if (isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'])) {echo $_SESSION['loggedIn'];}?>',
      sessionFirstName: '<?php if (isset($_SESSION['firstName'])) {echo $_SESSION['firstName'];}?>',
      sessionLastName: '<?php if (isset($_SESSION['lastName'])) {echo $_SESSION['lastName'];}?>',
      sessionPhoneNumber: '<?php if (isset($_SESSION['phoneNumber'])) {echo $_SESSION['phoneNumber'];}?>',
      sessionCompanyName: '<?php  if (isset($_SESSION['companyName'])) {echo $_SESSION['companyName'];}?>',
      admin: '<?php if (isset($_SESSION['admin'])) {echo $_SESSION['admin'];}?>'
    },
    created: function() {
      this.loginSub = false;
    },
    methods: {
      submit: function() {
        this.loginSub = true;
        if (this.userName.length >= 8 && this.password.length >= 8) {
          var jsonString = JSON.stringify({
            userName: this.userName,
            password: this.password
          });
          $.ajax({
            url: "login.php",
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: jsonString,
            success: function(data) {
              var vueapp = this;
              vueapp.response = data;
              vueapp.error = data.error;
              if(data.success==true){location.reload();}
              console.log(data);
            }.bind(this)
          });
        }
      },
        showResetPasswordForm: function(){
            this.error=false;
            this.userName='';
            this.password='';
            this.showLoginContent=false;
            this.showResetPasswordContent=true;
            this.userFound=true;
            this.passwordResetSuccess=false;
            this.loginSub=false;
        },
        showLoginForm: function(){
        this.error=false;
        this.userName='';
        this.password='';
        this.showResetPasswordContent=false;
        this.showLoginContent=true;
        this.userFound=true;
        this.passwordResetSuccess=false;
        this.loginSub=false;
    },
        resetLoginFormFields: function(){
            this.error=false;
            this.userName='';
            this.password='';
            this.showLoginContent=true;
            this.showResetPasswordContent=false;
            this.userFound=true;
            this.passwordResetSuccess=false;
            this.loginSub=false;
        },
        resetPassword: function(){
            console.log('ranResetPassword');
        this.loginSub = true;
        if (this.userName.length >= 1) {
          var jsonString = JSON.stringify({
            userName: this.userName
          });
          $.ajax({
            url: "passwordReset.php",
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: jsonString,
            success: function(data) {
              var vueapp = this;
              vueapp.error = data.error;
              vueapp.userFound=data.userFound;
              if(data.success==true){this.passwordResetSuccess=true;}
              console.log(data);
            }.bind(this)
          });
        }
        }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Do any of your forms even have buttons?

Comment: No they are all outside of the form  as I dont need them because they are submiting with ajax

Comment: Then the type of the button is irrelevant to your problem.

Comment: Pressing enter on the form doesn't require a button for said action to result in the form submitting. Add a handler for the form's submit event that instead calls your method and prevents the default.

Comment: how would I prevent default with a handeler? could you give me an example

Comment: vue has a few built-in options for that. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

Answer (score -1):

`<form role="form" onsubmit="return false">` seems to work. However I still dont know why it was submiting. Any ideas?